# Problem with turtlebot bringup minimal on Fuerte

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the Turtlebot tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/groovy/TurtleBot%20Bringup. I am attempting to run the command:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/xacro.py", line 35, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 554, in main
    process_includes(doc, os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1]))
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 193, in process_includes
    filename = eval_text(elt.getAttribute('filename'), {})
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 409, in eval_text
    results.append(handle_extension(lex.next()[1][2:-1]))
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 397, in handle_extension
    return eval_extension("$(%s)" % s)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/src/xacro.py", line 53, in eval_extension
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(str, resolve_anon=False)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 203, in resolve_args
    resolved = _find(resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 139, in _find
    return resolved[0:idx-len(arg)] + r.get_path(args[0]) + resolved[idx:]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 164, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: create_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [3]=/home/bennie/fuerte_workspace
while processing /home/bennie/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot-master/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/_robot.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/xacro/xacro.py '/home/bennie/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot-master/turtlebot_description/robots/create_circles_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
```

Note that I am simply using a Create base and not an actual Turtlebot. The thing is that I was able to run the above command without problem before I upgrated Ubuntu (12.04) with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I tried the following (http://answers.ros.org/question/57161/turtlebot_bringup-error-invalid-param-tag/) to fix my problem, but it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62902/problem-with-turtlebot-bringup-minimal-on-fuerte/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, so I fixed my problem by reinstalling all Turtlebot packages. I didn't think it would be as simple as that. I won't update my packages anymore!

---

Originally posted by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) with karma: 343 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1